# PhantomJS script to select from dropdown menu, fill a cell, hit download button and save resulting file

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am trying to automate some data collection for my research: one piece of it comes from [this website](https://data.sca.isr.umich.edu/data-archive/mine.php), which has recently transitioned to a responsive format -- data are not accessible from a precise URL but come as output of selecting options in the page.

Now, I thought to write down a JavaScript code to select the data cut and have PhantomJS run it on the page. My problem is that I am totally new to JavaScript and this piece is likely the only thing I will ever use JS for, hence I do not know where to start.

I would like the script to go to the webpage, select an item from the dropdown menu, select one of the four options, fill the cell with a certain year, and finally hit the 'download csv' button to save the file. If anyone could provide snippets of code for me to put together or a commented script that would save me a good week of work!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could use Selenium to simulate that. A better way is just go straight to the data source by using requests and just iterate through the different parameters. This is using requests with python however.

So to get Table 5, year 2010, Monthly, in ascending order:

```
payload = {
'table': '5',
'year': '2010',
'qorm': 'M',
'order': 'asc',
'format': 'View Below'}
```

Full code something like this:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://data.sca.isr.umich.edu/data-archive/mine.php'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Mobile Safari/537.36'}

period = {'Monthly': 'M', 'Quarterly': 'Q', 'Annual': 'Y'}

payload = {
'table': '5',
'year': '2010',
'qorm': period['Monthly'],
'order': 'asc',
'format': 'View Below'}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
table = pd.read_html(response.text)[-1]

table.columns = table.loc[0]
table = table.loc[1:]

table.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print (table)
0   Month  Year  ... Current Index Expected Index
1       1  2010  ...          81.1           70.1
2       2  2010  ...          81.8           68.4
3       3  2010  ...          82.4           67.9
4       4  2010  ...            81           66.5
5       5  2010  ...            81           68.8
6       6  2010  ...          85.6           69.8
7       7  2010  ...          76.5           62.3
8       8  2010  ...          78.3           62.9
9       9  2010  ...          79.6           60.9
10     10  2010  ...          76.6           61.9
11     11  2010  ...          82.1           64.8
12     12  2010  ...          85.3           67.5
13      1  2011  ...          81.8           69.3
14      2  2011  ...          86.9           71.6
15      3  2011  ...          82.5           57.9
16      4  2011  ...          82.5           61.6
17      5  2011  ...          81.9           69.5
18      6  2011  ...            82           64.7
19      7  2011  ...          75.7           55.9
20      8  2011  ...          68.5           47.6
21      9  2011  ...          75.2           49.4
22     10  2011  ...          74.9           51.7
23     11  2011  ...          77.4           54.9
24     12  2011  ...          79.6           63.6
25      1  2012  ...          84.2           69.1
26      2  2012  ...            83           70.3
27      3  2012  ...            86           69.8
28      4  2012  ...          82.9           72.3
29      5  2012  ...          87.2           74.3
30      6  2012  ...          81.5           67.8
..    ...   ...  ...           ...            ...
88      4  2017  ...         112.7             87
89      5  2017  ...         111.7           87.7
90      6  2017  ...         112.4           83.8
91      7  2017  ...         113.4           80.5
92      8  2017  ...         110.9           87.7
93      9  2017  ...         111.7           84.4
94     10  2017  ...         116.5           90.5
95     11  2017  ...         113.5           88.9
96     12  2017  ...         113.8           84.3
97      1  2018  ...         110.5           86.3
98      2  2018  ...         114.9             90
99      3  2018  ...         121.2           88.8
100     4  2018  ...         114.9           88.4
101     5  2018  ...         111.8           89.1
102     6  2018  ...         116.5           86.3
103     7  2018  ...         114.4           87.3
104     8  2018  ...         110.3           87.1
105     9  2018  ...         115.2           90.5
106    10  2018  ...         113.1           89.3
107    11  2018  ...         112.3           88.1
108    12  2018  ...         116.1             87
109     1  2019  ...         108.8           79.9
110     2  2019  ...         108.5           84.4
111     3  2019  ...         113.3           88.8
112     4  2019  ...         112.3           87.4
113     5  2019  ...           110           93.5
114     6  2019  ...         111.9           89.3
115     7  2019  ...         110.7           90.5
116     8  2019  ...         105.3           79.9
117     9  2019  ...         108.5           83.4

[117 rows x 9 columns]
```

Comment: neat, the original code is in R though, I think R's `httr` might work in a similar way without resorting to a second language.